# Check if Mac App was taken from Mac App Store with Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, macos, licensing, store

I'm trying to give a license to all the users who have bought my app from Mac App Store in order to give them faster updates. 
What i was thinking is to do an update for the Mac App Store version of the app that will let user register from within the application itself. But i'm having problems figuring out how to test if the application was really taken from Mac App Store and not from a pirated source. 
Is there a way to test if the user bought the app from AppStore. Apple does not release this info - as if it would - i could just test if that user email is in the list of people who downloaded the app from AppStore.

Thank you in advance for the help,
Bogdan Vladu

Comment: You're asking if there's a way to compute whether or not a given input is in an unknown set.  There isn't.  Can you make every version downloaded slightly different, e.g. give them serial numbers?  I doubt Apple would let you.  If they _are_ watermarking everything, they sure as heck won't let you in on it.

Comment: I want to release my app on another store also - that will let me make faster updates - and i want to give to the users who have already bought the app from Mac App Store license for the version of the app from the other store, so they also can take advantage of faster updates letting them know that if they choose to take the app from the other store they will no more update through MacAppStore

Comment: That's really nice.  But it's like asking you to sort a list without telling you what half of the values are.  You can't do it without the information that you're not getting.

Comment: Yes - so thats why i want to use another way - maybe to test if the binary is valid and it wasn't tempered with. Something to do with codesign - but not really sure how to use Security framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have the MAS version of your application copy the Apple-issued receipt to the Application Support folder.

The independent version could look there for a valid receipt. If there is, it will behave like the fully licensed version. If there is not, it would go to demo mode.

Comment: This is what I do in my apps.  I think Daniel Jalkut first blogged about the method a while back: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/1678/this-app-is-your-app

Comment: This looks exactly like what i need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're making enough money from this app to pay money for DRM and obsfucation, go for it.  It might slow down the pirates enough for it to be a profit for you.

Otherwise, you're pitting your own time and skill against everyone who's interested in pirating your app.  It's a losing battle, unless your app is really unpopular, in which case you've lost again.

In short, there's no algorithmic way of making sure.  Code obsfucation is the way to go, and hope that the pirates don't find the "check-for-tampering" module.